# Solo obtengo el último objeto del forEach

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que se llama 4 veces, `addRowInput`, y se manda junto con 4 valores: `(x, mag, label y type)`

```
var personalForm = ()=>{
      id0.addRowInput(x,"head",  "Tarifa", "head", {noAddRow:true});  
      id0.addRowInput(x,"power", "Power",  "input");  
      id0.addRowInput(x,"energy","Energy", "input");  
      id0.addRowInput(x,"btn",   "Button", "btn");
   }
```

Dicha función los recoge, y manda 3 de ellos `(mag, label y type)` a `sndFrm` al final de esta.

Una vez llamada `sndFrm`, reúne los 3 valores cada vez que se ejecuta:

[image: Llamadas con los valores asociados]

```
/*Fragmento correspondiente*/
sndFrm(mag, label, type){
      console.log('Llamada del mag: '+mag);
      console.log('Llamada del label: '+label);
      console.log('Llamada del type: '+type);
      console.log(' ');
```

Hasta aquí está todo perfecto, ya que puedo imprimir todos los valores en orden de entrada. El problema viene cuando intento hacer un bucle forEach, el cual me debería seleccionar todos los div[data-group] uno por uno y aplicarles la siguiente regla:

```
this.contentForm.querySelectorAll("div[data-group]").forEach(item=>{

         let obj = {
            Type : type, Label : label
         };
console.log(obj);
```

Hasta donde yo entiendo de los bucles (que por lo visto es poco), debería poder asignar el valor `type` en orden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y creo que aquí comienza a radicar el problema, por culpa del bucle foreach, hace las llamadas escalonadas y siempre que intente obtener el valor de los objetos me va a devolver el último.

¿Habría alguna otra solución que no usase el bucle forEach, porque creo que es el causante de toda la funcionalidad de este código?

Comment: En el evento no se ve la llamada a sndForm, sino a personalForm

Comment: Perdón, en el evento está la llamada a addRowInput 4 veces, con los distintos valores con los que se mandan, dicha función hace un llamamiento también a sndFrm, pero al haber 4 llamadas desde el load, hay 4 llamadas en el sndFrm. Editado y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pasas la informacion al txtare, le dice igual a jsoned, mas no lo adicionas, en ese sentido el type btn va de ultimo. Si lo comentas, te aparecerá solo input, en resumidas cuenta solo te aparecerá el ultimo, debes crear una variable string si lo deseas ir añadiendo como string o un array en su defecto e ir añadiendo los objetos (esto es según lo que desees hacer).

this.txtare.value=jsoned;

En esta linea se iguala una variable a otra mas no se agrega.